# Don't make base class public while building objective c framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks

I am working on a framework project where I have a sub class implemented from base class. When I prepare build I am just making sub class public but not the base class which results the following lexical error:

> Lexical or Preprocessor Issue Group

But if I make the base class also public then it is okay. But I don't want to expose base class to the outer world. I mean don't want to make base class public.

Here is definition of base class

```
@interface BaseClass : NSObject
- (void)baseFunction;
@end
```

definition of sub class:

```
@interface SubClass : BaseClass
- (void)subFunction;
@end
```

and the header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FileUtil/SubClass.h>
```

Please let me know how I can overcome the situation. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this function declaration in `@implementation` file with `Extension` so it will hide from other user who will use your framework.

```
BaseClass.h

@interface BaseClass : NSObject
@end

BaseClass.m

@interface BaseClass ()
//its private method for out side class
- (void)baseFunction;
@end

@implementation BUViewController

@end
```

How by this example you can get some idea how to make private method to hide from others.